# phrase usage of 'best of the worst'

Tags: phrases

He just had a car accident, but the best of the worst is that no one got injured in that accident. Can I use 'best of the worst' like previous sentence?

Comment: You might use _but at least_

Comment: One that closely matches your target phrase is **good in the bad**. `He just had a car accident, but the good in the bad is that no one got injured.` It's not a common idiom, but is seen from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the meaning comes through pretty well, I'd advise against using it. It's definitely non-standard. A somewhat longer but clearer version would be (I think), "He had a car accident. The good news is that no one was hurt. The bad news is that the car was totaled."

Answer (score 2):

You might use **silver lining**. This is derived from the expression **Every cloud has a silver lining**, which means that there is always something good to be found in a bad situation.   Your phrase, **the best of the worst**, is not an idiom in English. Barmar and alpa's suggestions are also good.

Comment: This immediately sprang to mind, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure, but I might have used "fortunately no one got injured in that accident."

Comment: It is a good suggestion. A dictionary definition and an example from a dictionary would make it a great answer (and you would see from examples in a dictionary how fitting your word actually is). I'm referring to something like [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fortunately) but I'll leave it to you to [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/250659/edit) your answer however you think is appropriate :-)